# Generating child components in angular2 with NgFor does not work

Tags: angular

I'm using angular2 alpha 37.

I've defined a `<map>` component and a `<marker>` component (child of `<map>`).
The `<map>` component has a array data member which contains a list of marker coordinates. The `<map>` view should display all markers in the array

When defining the `<map>` view as follows (explicitly listing components for all array members):

```
@View({
  template:`
    <marker [model]="markers[0]"></marker>
    <marker [model]="markers[1]"></marker>
  `,
  directives:[Marker]
})
```

The `<marker>` components are updated whenever the corresponding array member changes. This is desired behaviour.

When defining the `<map>` view as follows (using `NgFor`):

```
@View({
  template: '<marker *ng-for="#m of markers" [model]="m"></marker>',
  directives:[Marker,NgFor]
})
```

a new marker is created whenever the array members change, which is not desirable.

Needles to say I would like to use the `NgFor` method.

I've no clue what is going on. How can I use `NgFor` but avoid that new `<marker>` instances are created whenever the individual markers update?

Comment: Some more info: when a `<marker>` component is created, it actually creates marker on a leaflet map. When the component is updarted, the marker on the map should update

Answer (score 3):

Split the list `ngFor` iterates over from the model data.

This is Dart code but shouldn't be hard to translate to TS

```dart
import 'dart:math' show Random;
import 'package:angular2/angular2.dart';

@Component(
    selector: 'app-element',
    template: '''
<h3>app-element</h3>
<map></map>
    ''',
    directives: const [MapComponent])
class AppElement {}
```

```dart
@Component(selector: 'map',
    template: '''
<button (click)="changeValue()">Change value</button>
<marker *ngFor="let m of markersIndexes" [model]="markers[m]"></marker>
<!-- use `markers[m]` to assign a model but `markersIndexes` for `*ng-for` -->
''',
    directives: const [MarkerComponent, NgFor])
class MapComponent {
  MapComponent() {
    markers = <Marker>[
      new Marker('m0', 0),
      new Marker('m1', 1),
      new Marker('m2', 2),
      new Marker('m3', 3)
    ];
    markersIndexes = new List<int>.generate(markers.length, (int index) => index);
  }
  List<Marker> markers; // model to pass to <marker>
  List<int> markersIndexes; // indexes used by *ng-for
  // when markers are added or removed markersIndexes need to by updated of course

  // Update random marker item with random position value    
  Random _rnd = new Random();
  void changeValue() {
    int idx = _rnd.nextInt(3);
    markers[idx].position = _rnd.nextInt(100);
  }
}
```

```dart
@Component(
    selector: 'marker',
    template: '''
<h3>marker</h3>
<div>name: {{model.name}} pos: {{model.position}} created: {{createdAt}}</div>
''',
    styles: const [
      '''
:host {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
'''
    ])
class MarkerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() Marker model;
  String createdAt;

  MarkerComponent() {
    createdAt = new DateTime.now().toString();
  }
  void ngOnInit() {
    print(model);
  }
}
```

```dart
// Marker model
class Marker {
  String name;
  int position;

  Marker(this.name, this.position);

  @override
  String toString() => 'Marker: $name - $position';
}
```

Comment: This works indeed as expected. It's a shame though that this explicit use of indices is required for this use case. I'll also check the other answer before granting final reward

Comment: Furthermore I'd expect the following to also work, but this is not the case: `<marker *ngFor="#m of markers;#i=index" [model]="markers[i]"></marker>`

Comment: And how does this scale when the `markers` array is dynamically changing length? The corresponding `markersIndexes` would need to be recalculated at all times?

Comment: You can just add remove at the end of the `markersIndexes` array. All elements (after the insert/remove position) will get values from a different `markers` position assigned to. I guess there are a lot of strategies to cope with this but there are not enough details about your actual use case and would probably need extensive benchmarking. You can also create your custom `ngFor` directive with different behavior if you want more control.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@View({
template:"<marker *ng-for="#m of markers" [model]="m">{{m}}</marker>",
 directives:[Marker,NgFor]
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but this yields the same results. On each change of `#m`, a new marker is created, instead of updated.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you use the `alpha37` version which remains an alpha version and you can have some bugs... I made some tests using the `beta0` version and it seems to work as expected. So I would recommend you to upgrade to this version... We expect beta versions to be more stable ;-)

Here is the code I used to made my test:

- Main component

  ```
  @Component({
      selector: 'first-app',
      template: `
        <map></map>
      `,
      directives: [ MapComponent ]
  })
  export class AppComponent {
  }
  ```
- `Marker` data object

  ```
  class Marker {
    name: string;
    position: int;

    constructor(name, position) {
      this.name = name;
      this.position = position;
    }
  }
  ```
- `Marker` component

  ```
  @Component({
    selector: 'marker',
    template:`
      <div class="marker">Marker {{model.name}} <button (click)="update()">Update</button></div>
    `,
    directives:[MarkerComponent]
  })
  export class MarkerComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() model: Marker;

    constructor() {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    update() {
      this.model.name = this.model.name + 'a';
    }
  }
  ```
- `Map` component

  ```
  @Component({
    selector: 'map',
    template:`
      <marker *ngFor="#m of markers" [model]="m"></marker>
      <button (click)="update()">Update</button>
    `,
    directives:[MarkerComponent]
  })
  export class MapComponent {
    constructor() {
      this.markers = [
        new Marker('m0', 0),
        new Marker('m1', 1),
        new Marker('m2', 2),
        new Marker('m3', 3)
      ];
    }

    update() {
      this.markers[1].name = 'm1a';
    }
  }
  ```

When I click on both update buttons, the name of the second marker is updated in the view and no additional `<marker>` element appears.

**Edit**

It could be the way you update the element in the list. Do you override it with a new instance or update the value of an attribute for an existant instance in the list? In the first case, I think that you could will a new element addition in the list.

```
update() {
  this.markers[1]= new Marker('m1a', 1);
}
```

After doing some tests, this approach works as well. No element added in the list.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks for your input. Prior to initiating the bounty, I upgraded to the latest beta. However this gave the same results.

Comment: Would you have a repo from where I can test? Thanks!

Comment: I made some additional tests but I can't reproduce your problem. I definitively need some stuff (plunkr or github repo) to be able to reproduce your problem and try to find out a fix ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. It's exactly what I was looking for. Quick question, why do you include MarkerComponent as a directive in MarkerComponent? Was that a copy & paste error?